# Alternative term to 'loyalize'

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

To ***[loyalize](http://www.yourdictionary.com/loyalize)*** is a  term which means:

> - To make someone loyal to a cause.

(Wiktionary)

> - '[Loyalize](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/20130510151514-17102372--loyalize-customers-by-remembering-their-needs)' Customers by Remembering Their Needs. (www.linkedin.com)

Unluckily the term is quite rare and probably obsolete ([see Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=loyalize&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cloyalize%3B%2Cc0)) but it exactlty carries  the meaning I want to convey.

The context can be that of a company which  wants lo "loyalize" clients, or more generally a (virtual) community which is looking to keep its members to avoid migrations to other communities.

Is there a more common alternative to *loyalize* or is a phrase the expresses the same concept  the only alternative?

Comment: How about *retention through loyalty*?

Comment: Yes,  the concept can be expressed via different phrases, and yours is a good one, but is there an alternative term to it?

Comment: @GrahamNicol *Retain* goes better with employees rather than customers. As *a retention fee* implies, usage of retention for customers is limited to some service sectors.

Comment: In modern usage, you're looking for their [*buy-in*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/buy-in).  It's a shame that there isn't a connected verb: to **"sell-in"**.

Comment: Reliable may be.

Comment: There are plenty of examples with negative connotations, like *brainwash* and *indoctrinate*, but positive ones are hard to come by...

Comment: _Brainwash_ seems pretty good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider [**retain customers**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=retaining+customers&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cretaining%20customers%3B%2Cc0)
.

> fidéliser une clientèle:  retain customers, create customer loyalty  ([**WordReference English-French Dictionary**](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/fid%C3%A9liser%20une%20client%C3%A8le))

Comment: Yer probably 'retain' is close, I was actually looking for the equivalent to the Italian 'fidelizzare' or the French 'fideliser'. It appears there is no perfect fit.

Answer (score 0):

How about "**recruit**"?

In the definitions [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/recruit), 9 and 10 are probably most relevant:

- to attempt to acquire the services of (a person) for an employer
- to attempt to enroll or enlist (a member, affiliate, student, or the like)

Comment: That's interesting, but the idea is more  on  keeping customers, users you already have (to avoid losing them) rather than attracting new ones.

Answer (score 0):

What about using the words like:

*dedicated

*attached

*allegiant

*Fidelity,

with any supporting verb to mean the customers are unwaveringly with the company.

As for verbs, we may use 'attach' or 'agglutinate.

Comment: None of these is a verb.